# What is causing "Use of unresolved identifier ParseClientConfiguration"?

Tags: swift, parse-server

I'm on the final step of migrating from Parse to Heroku. I just need to update the code in my app to include the new keys and sever info. I put in this code:

```
    let config = ParseClientConfiguration(block: {
        (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in

        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "...";
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "...";
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "...";
    });

    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(config);
```

And I get the error on the first line.

I have already imported Parse, so I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting this.

Comment: "unresolved identifier" alwyas has the same cause: the compiler doesn't know what your object is, it can't find the declaration. In your case, the compiler doesn't know what is `ParseClientConfiguration` so it's an "unresolved" object, it can't be used. It may be because of a faulty import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using an outdated Parse SDK. I had to update. All is working now.

Comment: Did you need to import anything else? I updated my SDK am I'm still getting this error. When I import the ParseClientConfiguration.h (I'm using Objective-C) it gives me a bunch of errors.

Comment: I only imported Parse and UIKit.

Comment: Ok I figured out what my issue was. Even though I removed the old Parse framework from the project. I also have to delete the files from the workspace. I imported the new SDK using cocoapods, but the old one was somehow still overriding it.

Comment: I tried all these things but still getting same error